# Can I change the font color of specific keywords in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

So I've figured out how to change the color of keywords in Visual Studio (for c# dev), but I was wondering if I can change the color for specific keywords. For example, I want to emulate the syntax highlighting color scheme that vim uses. Vim uses green for some keywords, maroon for others (ex: public is green, if is maroon). As far as I can tell, the keyword font color attribute in the environment -> fonts and colors is a catch all color for every keyword. Is there a way to change, say, if and new to maroon and leave public green, or some plugin that will help me do this?

Comment: Possibly with the Microsoft Compiler Services (Rosyln) but that is a lot of work if you are not familiar with it.